# A man is trapped in a cave, deals with Zooks and prehistoric fish

Tags: story-identification, novel

This is a novel I read several (30)? Years ago. It is about a man trapped in a cave. He has an (imagery)? Creature call a (zook)? There are prehistoric fish that he catches and gets oil from to make fire. That's all I remember.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the fantasy or science fiction aspects?

Comment: And I am really not certain what you mean by "He has an (imagery)?" Are you saying he has something that you think may be called an "imagery"? Do you remember anything about what it does?

Comment: Can't speak for the OP, but I'd guess they meant to type 'imaginary' rather than 'imagery.' Of course, that begs the question as to whether any of this qualifies as genuine fantasy (or sci-fi). I guess a man catching prehistoric fish in modern times might count? (Assuming this book is set in modern times.)

Comment: "Imagery" -> "[Imaginary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imaginary)"?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you remember the novel "The SkooK', by J. P. Miller. A man named Spanish Barman is trapped in a cave, where a character that he created for his daughters' bedtime stories appears and assists him. The cave has a subterranean sea within, inhabited by giant plesiosaurs and giant sea-bears, as well as the fish.
[image]